# How to reuse the same sequelize connection anywhere in my Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Here is my problem, I have an Express app where I separate the controllers (i.e. the functions called for each route) from the application entry point:

**index.js**

```
...
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
const PersonController = require('controllers/PersonController');
router.route('/persons').get(PersonController.index)
...
```

**controllers/PersonController.js**

```
...
exports.index = (req, res) => {
  //Return all the lines of the `Persons` table
};
...
```

But to access the database, I must have access to the `sequelize` instance in my controllers. How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways...

My favorite : you can create your constroller as a class...

Here is a kind of code, (not the best, but something running)

**Controller class**

```
class PersonController {
      constructor(sequelize) {
           this.sequelize = sequelize;
      }

      index(req, res){
           const sequelize = sequelize;
           ... your code ...
      }

}

module.exports = PersonController;
```

**After**

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
const PersonController = require('controllers/PersonController');

router.route('/persons').get((req, res) => {
     const controller = new PersonController(sequelize);
     controller.index(req, res);
})
```

Comment: Thank you :) I would only instantiate the controller outside the closure in order to reuse it for each route, ie: `const pc = new PersonController(sequelize); router.route('/persons').get(pc.index).post(pc.store)...`

Comment: Oops, we must bind `this`: `.get(pc.index.bind(pc)).post(pc.store(pc)...`